# Wordpress plugin for donation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, paypal, payment, donations

I am trying these wordpress plugins for donation.

**Smart donation**

**Seamless Donation**

**PayPal Donation**

But these are not according to my requirements.

I want same like this example.

https://faith4life.cc/dallas/donate/

Payment should proceed in tow process. Same as in above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the site you provided is not a wordpress website.

Secondly, there are many ways to get such donation system. But you need to know that for accepting payments ON your website you need merchant account like from Authorize.net - otherwise, you can't just ask people to enter their credit card numbers on your website.

For wordpress, i suggest you to use Gravity Forms as Gravity forms provide many payment gateways addons which are quiet good and integrate seamlessly with Paypal or Authorize.net as well (if you want to receive payments on your website).

For gravity forms, visit: http://www.gravityforms.com/ and for Addons visit: http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/authorize-net/

I have suggested Gravity forms & authorize.net addon because we are using it for our website & while integrating some payment system for our website, we looked into a lot many solutions and found this as best solution.

Comment: The website That I provide is not a wordpress website. But I say I want same as that...

Comment: That's why i have suggested you a solution for your problem based on Wordpress because you wrote Wordpress in Question and tagged your Question in `wordpress` as well.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Easy Paypal Payment or Donation Accept Plugin is an easy to use WordPress plugin to Accept Paypal payment for a service or a product or Donation in one click. Can be used in the sidebar, posts and pages.

http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-easy-paypal-payment-or-donation-accept-plugin-120

**[Custom Post Donations](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-donations/)**